# How can I fix tmux not showing messages at startup?

Tags: tmux

I have a command in my `.tmux.conf` file which checks to see if a directory exists, then displays a message if it doesn't; and another command which tries to run a shell script.

file: `~/.tmux.conf`

```
# do a check and display message if non-zero exit
if-shell "! [-d $HOME/.tmux]" 'display-message "tmux plugins are not installed"'

# try run a shell script
run-shell ~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/resurrect.tmux
```

The problem is that tmux won't display any messages that are generated during startup - which is the time I would expect diagnostic errors and warnings to be generated.

What I start tmux, I get an error message in tmux's pager

```
(null):0: no current session
```

where it's clearly not liking being sent messages.

If I run the same commands by using `source-file ~/.tmux-conf` in the middle of a tmux session, all messages are reported successfully.
How can I get tmux to report messages during startup?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was also interested in displaying some sort of startup message and came across this question. After searching around I eventually found out about tmux hooks [(introduced internally in tmux 2.2)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES) which can be configured to display a one time startup message (read more [here](https://devel.tech/tips/n/tMuXz2lj/the-power-of-tmux-hooks/)).

You can use the `session-created` hook to run tmux commands on a new session. `display-message -p "message"` outputs a message straight to the newly created window. So you can display a message like so:

```
MESSAGE='display-message -p "tmux plugins are not installed" ; \
         display-message -p "please press Leader + I to install" ; \
         set-hook -gu session-created ;'
if-shell "[ ! -d $HOME/.tmux ]" 'set-hook -g session-created ${MESSAGE}'
```

the `set-hook -gu session-created` unregisters this hook, so that this message is shown only on the *first* session created, and not all subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me from the command-line as follows:

```
tmux new-session \; if-shell "! [-d $HOME/.tmux]" 'display-message "tmux plugins are not installed"'
```